# Favicon is not displaying correctly when link is sent on instagram

Tags: javascript, html, css, favicon

When I send my website URL on Instagram the image that it displays is not the image I want to have displayed. My website has a Favicon set and the favicon sends correctly when the URL is sent through text. How do I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Please add your url here at the very least. The HTML tag will also help us answer.

Comment: I really don't think this is a favicon issue. As @RahulPurohit pointed out, being able to actually see the url or some `HTML` would be helpful. If I were to give it my best guess, you need to add a `<meta property="og:image" content="/path/to/thumbnail.webp" />`

Comment: The website url is safechoiceusa.com. I tried adding the suggestion however the issue remains. On safechoiceusa.com/index.html you see the code without the meta property for the image and then on safechoiceusa.com/articles.html you can see the code with the image meta properties. Any suggestions?

Comment: @andrilla I have included the response and URL above

Comment: @ohmygodimpregnant Can you try switching your `webp` image to `png`? This can be due to support issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need add some metadata in head section.
Check it here: https://web.dev/learn/html/metadata/

here is the code you need to add

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Machine Learning Workshop" />
<meta property="og:description" content="School for Machines Who Can't Learn Good and Want to Do Other Stuff Good Too"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.machinelearningworkshop.com/image/all.png" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="Black and white line drawing of refrigerator, french door refrigerator, range, washer, fan, microwave, vaccuum, space heater and air conditioner" />
```

https://web.dev/learn/html/metadata/#open-graph

Comment: Hi @dzm11 thank you for the suggestion but it did not seem to work. I have added the website URL maybe that will assist